# Javascript for changing form border color doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to animate the border color of a form but doesn't seem to be running.I want the border color to change automatically without any user interaction once the page loads.

```
window.onload(function colormagic() {
  //alert("OK1")
  var blueborder = document.getElementById("form1")
  var colorarray = new array()
  colorarray[0] =  "blue"
  colorarray[1] = "green"
  colorarray[2] = "yellow"
  colorarray[3] =  "blue"
  colorarray[4] =  "green"
  colorarray[5] = "yellow"
  //alert("OK2")
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    blueborder.style.borderColor=colorarray[i];
    //alert("OK3")
  }
})
```

So i tried adding alert to debug it. And I am only getting the first alert statement.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1SRaoO7ZVd9cE4zbi0wZmxOblE/edit?usp=sharing this is the full html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this and it doesn't seem very friendly but maybe this is close to what [you're looking for](http://jsfiddle.net/7rbYN/6/). Of course you can set the timeout interval to your liking.

```
var form = document.getElementById('form1');

function colormagic() {    
    var colorarray = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
    var len = colorarray.length;
    var index = (Math.floor(Math.random() * len) + 1) - 1;

    form.style.borderColor = colorarray[index];

    setTimeout(colormagic, 100);
}

window.onload = colormagic;
```

Few improvements:

- There's no point of querying the DOM every time you loop so the first line is taken out of the loop
- style.borderColor isn't a function
- You needn't create an array with `new Array()` and assign individual indecies when you can just do `var arr = [colors, go, in, like, this];`

Comment: Basically, timers aren't accurate. Using `setInterval` will continue to queue up more function calls at the specified interval even if things start to slow down and the timers become more "off". `setTimeout` will only queue up the next function call of itself after the first call has already fired. So if timings start to deviate from the timeout you specified, it will at most only have 1 late function call queued up because it waits to call itself. That explanation might have be confusing so maybe this article will help [clear things for you](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)

Comment: Exactly what I am trying to do .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, this works

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5HFJ2/1/)** demo

```
window.onload = function colormagic() {
            var blueborder = document.getElementById("form1");
            var colorarray = new Array();
            colorarray[0] =  "blue"
            colorarray[1] = "green"
            colorarray[2] = "yellow"
            colorarray[3] =  "blue"
            colorarray[4] =  "green"
            colorarray[5] = "yellow"

            for (i = 0; i < colorarray.length; i++) {
                blueborder.style.borderColor = colorarray[i];
            }                 
}
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1SRaoO7ZVd9cE4zbi0wZmxOblE/edit?usp=sharing this is the full html file

Comment: That fixed the issue but it was too fast.Do you know how to keep it running?